# StringUtils issue in splitting comma containing strings

Tags: java, arrays, apache-stringutils

I want to parse this String Content.

```
   requiredContent='Tigers that breed with lions give birth to hybrids known as "tigons" and "ligers."// In 19th-century Sweden, 380 kids were strangled by their mothers or nurses every year, according to the Swedish Statistical Bureau.'
```

I split it with

```
 String[] factsArray = StringUtils.split(requiredContent, "//");
```

and I got the result

```
  [Tigers that breed with lions give birth to hybrids known as "tigons" and "ligers.", In 19th-century Sweden,  380 kids were strangled by their mothers or nurses every year,  according to the Swedish Statistical Bureau.]
```

The resultant factsArray should have an array length of 2 but it was showing an array of length 4.It was parsing the string which has "," included in the string.This should not happen ,How to fix this ???

Answer (score 0):

It's just a conflict in the display between array comma separator and string comma

verify `factsArray.length` result, it's 2 and not 4

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the string to use double quotes and escape them for the words tigons and ligers and tried to reproduce the problem. Using ApacheCommons lang3 version 3.4:

```
String requiredContent =  "Tigers that breed with lions give birth to hybrids known as \"tigons\" and \"ligers.\"// In 19th-century Sweden, 380 kids were strangled by their mothers or nurses every year, according to the Swedish Statistical Bureau.";
String[] factsArray = StringUtils.split(requiredContent, "//");
```

And I do get an array length of 2. I think the display of the array content could be messed up.

Answer (score 0):

i got array length 2

```
String requiredContent =  "Tigers that breed with lions give birth to hybrids known as \"tigons\" and \"ligers.\"// In 19th-century Sweden, 380 kids were strangled by their mothers or nurses every year, according to the Swedish Statistical Bureau.";
        List factsArray = StringUtils.split(requiredContent, "//", true);
        for (int i = 0; i < factsArray.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(factsArray.get(i));
        }
output:

Tigers that breed with lions give birth to hybrids known as "tigons" and "ligers."
 In 19th-century Sweden, 380 kids were strangled by their mothers or nurses every year, according to the Swedish Statistical Bureau.
```